# Find the measure of the smallest positive angle $\theta$ in degrees for which $\tan\theta=\frac{\cos25^\circ+\cos85^\circ}{\sin25^\circ-\sin85^\circ}$

Tags: trigonometry

I'm preparing for a math competition, and was stumped by this problem. The original problem is shown below, and the correct answer is $120°$. I'm posting this here to ask for explanation on how this answer was reached.

The equation given is $$\tan\theta={{\cos5°\cos20°+\cos35°\cos50°-\sin5°\sin20°-\sin35°\sin50°}\over{\sin5°\cos20°-\sin35°\cos50°+\cos5°\sin20°-\cos35°\sin50°}}$$

I was able to simplify the numerator using $\cos(x+y)=\cos(x)\cos(y)-\sin(x)\sin(y)$, and simplify the denominator using $\sin(x+y)=\sin(x)\cos(y)+\sin(y)\cos(x)$ to get the expression given in the title of this question, but I don't know how to go any further, or if this is even the right first step.

[image]

Comment: Do you know the formulas for $\sin a-\sin b$ and $\cos a+\cos b?$

Comment: @NicholesCortes Welcome to Math SE. FYI, related to Thomas Andrews' comment above, please see the "Sum-to-product" table in the [Product-to-sum and sum-to-product identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) section of Wikipedia's "List of trigonometric identities" article.

Comment: $$\cos(a + b) = \cos(a)\cos(b) - \sin(a)\sin(b).$$ $$~\cos(a - b) = \cos(a)\cos(b) +\sin(a)\sin(b).$$  $$\sin(a + b) = \sin(a)\cos(b) + \cos(a)\sin(b).$$ $$\sin(a - b) = \sin(a)\cos(b) - \cos(a)\sin(b).$$ From these identities, you can derive that $$\cos(a) + \cos(b) = 2 ~\cos\left( ~\dfrac{a+b}{2} ~\right) ~\cos\left( ~\dfrac{a-b}{2} ~\right),$$ $$\sin(a) - \sin(b) = 2 ~\sin\left( ~\dfrac{a-b}{2} ~\right) ~\cos\left( ~\dfrac{a+b}{2} ~\right).$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have: $\tan(\theta)=\dfrac{\cos(25^{\circ})+\cos(85^{\circ})}{\sin(25^{\circ}) - \sin(85^{\circ})}=\dfrac{2\cos(55^{\circ})\cos(30^{\circ})}{-2\cos(55^{\circ})\sin(30^{\circ})}=-\cot(30^{\circ})=-\sqrt{3} \implies \theta = 120^{\circ}$ would be the smallest positive angles satisfy the equation.